# resize image in openpyxl

Tags: python, waveform, pyvisa

I am trying to scale the image in the PIL style so that I can maintain the aspect ratio. it appears the openpyxl image does not have resize attribute. I get the error "AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'resize'". If I use PIL for resizing, then I get error adding the image "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment". 
Is there a way to rescale the image, the way I am trying to do.

```
import openpyxl
import PIL
from PIL import ImageGrab
#from PIL import Image
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image


image_scale=2

column_start=3
row_start=3

def screen_capture():
    img=ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save('test.jpg','JPEG')

def screen_scaling():
    image_scale=3
    img = Image('test.jpg')
    img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]/image_scale), int(img.size[1]/image_scale)),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save('test.jpg','JPEG')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
screen_capture()
screen_scaling()
img1=Image('test.jpg')
img1.anchor = ws.cell(row=row_start, column=column_start).coordinate
ws.add_image(img1)
wb.save('Save_test_data.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file pointer fp, which can be obtained by calling BytesIO on the image binary obtained by the get request, or it can be obtained by directly opening the file path.
2. Open this file pointer with pillow to get the PILImage image object, and use its resize function to zoom,
3. Manually assign a file pointer to the zoomed image object, and use it to generate a new XLImage image object
4. Calling openpyxl's add_image function will not report an error as you.

   ```
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLImage
    from PIL import Image as PILImage
    from io import BytesIO

    fp = BytesIO(imageBytes)
    fp.seek(0)
    img = PILImage.open(fp)
    resizedImg = img.resize(size)
    resizedImg.fp = fp
    resizedImg = XLImage(resizedImg)
    ws.add_image(resizedImg,"A1")
   ```